# Application Insights performance

Tags: performance, wcf, azure-application-insights

We have application insights running on a web application deployed to a public interface on IIS. After approx. 1 hour of test usage (8-10 concurrent users) all requests enter a long running state (1-2 minutes) before performance returns to normal. This pattern happens at regular intervals during the day generally in line with usage. 
Removing App Insights "fixes" the problem. Put Insights back in, problem re-occurs.
What we know:

1. PerfMon counters: CPU, Memory, Network Interface, Disk I/O, % maxConcurrentCalls, % maxConcurrentInstances show **no** spikes during the bottleneck
2. A firewall blocks the outbound App Insights call and the request is left to timeout
3. No IIS Events are raised (w3wp crash / app pool recycling) around the bottleneck time
4. WCF configuration is default

Given the frequency of the App Insight calls and the fact they are blocked and left to timeout I would expect the number of threads to max out and cause the bottleneck, but I would not expect it to return to normal after 1-2 minutes given the processing of the queued requests would equally trigger App Insight calls.

What is the counter here that shows the bottleneck and why does performance return to normal when it *should* stay choked.

Comment: Either unblock the firewall or remove App Insights. App Insights caches the requests it failed to send and tries to send them periodically. The batch fails and times out. Is there a point to the question?

Comment: Yes. What counters / events would demonstrate what is happening? The firewall can't be removed and App Insights has been. The question asks how to provide analysis with data for root cause. Large governmental bodies aren't satisfied with "it's fixed"

Comment: You added monitoring that tries to call a *blocked* server. There is nothing more to explain. You (the team) shouldn't have added it in the first place, or you should have found a monitoring solution acceptable to the client. Removing monitoring didn't fix anything, it just means that said large governmental body is now flying blind. Remember the Australian census

Comment: As for indicators, and purely from an academic perspective, look at App Insights documentation to see where it caches its events.

Comment: Maybe it gives up when it can't get rid of the backlog of tracking events.

If you know that the requests are blocked, then either don't use app insights, or open the firewall. The host names / IP addresses are listed here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-ip-addresses/